# Embed in slash commands doesn't work discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm working on a discord.js v13 bot with slash commands.
I'm trying to make a command that replies with an embed.
It doesn't give errors in the console but it gives an error in the message, here's an image:

[image]

Here's my code:

```js
const { MessageEmbed, Permissions } = require("discord.js");
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders");

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder().setName("ahelp").setDescription("Get information about how to use the asking command"),
    // komutu geliştirmek istersen guide: https://v13.discordjs.guide/interactions/slash-commands.html#options
    run: async (client, interaction) => {
        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`How to Make BrainCord <:logo:1079747150113681458> realize what you want!`)
            .setTimestamp()
            .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.avatarURL({ dynamic: true }))

            .setDescription(
                `> **Firstly : You need to make the prompt is __easy to realize and slightly long__ so the bot can realize exactly what you want.**

> **Secondly : Avoid writing the command like this B! <prompt> because the bot will think that the __" "__ is a thing that you want __write it like this B!<prompt>__.**

> **Thirdly : Care about the __punctuation__ in the prompt to make the bot know if it's a question or another thing.**

> **Fourthly : Then in the end the command to ask is __B!<prompt>__ not anything else.**

> __**Important Notes**__
> 1 : **Automatic Decline inappropriate requests**
> 2 : **May occasionally generates incorrect information**
> 3 : **limited knowledge of world and events after 2021**
`
            )
            .setColor("#2F3136")
            .setFooter(message.guild.name, message.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true }));

        //return embed

        interaction.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
    },
};
```

Comment: Based on the information you've provided, it seems that the error is, most likely, caught in your command handler. To better understand the issue and provide a solution, it would be helpful if you could log the error to the console and include it in your question. This will provide more context and allow us to provide a more accurate answer.

Comment: Also, in the embed, you are using `message.author.tag`, `message.author.avatarURL()` etc. without even defining what `message` is anywhere

Answer (score 0):

First of all, using `run: async (..)` is a wrong choice of execution, since it isn't practical with certain modules of discord.js .

Secondly, in your command handler you need to put in your `execute(..)` message aswell.

For the embed, in discord.js v13 the use of the embed builder is :

```js
const embedName = new EmbedBuilder()
  .setName("Name")
  .setDescription("Description");
  
interaction.reply({embeds: [embedName]})
```

As for another error I noticed, `message.author` is false or undefined per definition, since you reply to an interaction, on `interactionCreate`. So there is an interaction, but no message.

That means you need to replace `message.guild.name` and `message.guild.iconUrl(...)` with `interaction.guild.name` and `interaction.guild.iconUrl(...)`

Final thing I noticed, is that it is very hard to read your code. If you're using VSC, then you can install Prettier and add it to your code, elseway you can do something like:

```js
function()
  .option1()
  .option2()
  ...
  .option9();

function2()
  .option1()
  .option2();
  
...
```

If my answer works or is helpful please upvote or verify it as I need to unlock some StackOverflow functions.

Cordially, Kama